# Bezier segment node not accepting inputs

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to randomize the start and end handle position for a "Bezier Segment" node, but any time I connect a random value vector to the input socket I just get an error (see example image below). I'm new to blender so maybe I'm misunderstanding what type of input is required, but the purple color indicates that I should be able to input a vector, right?

[image]

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need a single value for the ID in the Random Value node so it produces a single output (circular shape of the output).

[image: ID single input]

I think that the default value it uses as ID when nothing is specified is *Index*, which doesn't makes sense when generating a single value, so we need to specify a single ID.

**Edit**:

From Blender documentation:

> **ID**
>
> An ID to drive the random number generator seed. By default, this input uses the same value as of the ID Node, which is the *id* attribute of the context geometry if it exists, and otherwise the index.

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved

Comment: @JosephCriscione - If this answered your question satisfactorily, please consider clicking the (accepted) checkmark next to the answer. This will help direct future users experiencing similar problems to this _correct_  answer.